# How can i get a Grayscale color space?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, grayscale

[image]

Hi, my work requires me to produce icons that are grayscale in color space. everytime i export icons from illustrator it comes out as RGB. i even made new files with converted color>convert to grayscale, but it still ended up as RGB. i'm not sure how to proceed. if anyone can helpme, a big thanks!

Comment: Just convert the file to grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator only has CMYK & RGB. Bring the files into Photoshop and convert to Grayscale from the Image > Mode menu.

Comment: thanks! after i was stumped i did all my icons that way. so theres isn't any way from illustrator export settings to have grayscale, right? :)

Comment: you can export them grayscale as in "all colors are shades of gray" (which is what convert to grayscale does), but as far as the Color Mode goes Illustrator only works/exports in CMYK & RGB. So if your work cares about color mode and not colors per se, you have to bring them in Photoshop. If you have a lot of icons I'd suggest looking into Photoshop Scripting/Actions so you won't have to manually convert an entire folder one by one.

Comment: thanks rubens, this saves me a bunch! 